# Unable to start SonarQube, Getting Error in Terminal

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube, java-11, apple-m1

I am trying to implement **SonarQube** on my Mac Pro M1.

I have followed steps from: [here](https://medium.com/@pranay.urkude/sonarqube-integration-with-ios-b76df8405014)

Also I have installed JDK 11.
But getting **Error**:

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library because none of the
jvm 1    |           following files:
jvm 1    |             libwrapper-macosx-aarch64-64.dylib
jvm 1    |             libwrapper-macosx-universal-64.dylib
jvm 1    |             libwrapper.dylib
jvm 1    |           could be located on the following java.library.path:
jvm 1    |             /Applications/SonarQube/bin/macosx-universal-64/./lib
jvm 1    |           Please see the documentation for the wrapper.java.library.path
jvm 1    |           configuration property.
jvm 1    |           System signals will not be handled correctly.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /Applications/SonarQube/temp
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:58182]
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/Applications/SonarQube/elasticsearch]: /Applications/SonarQube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:416)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.setSecurityManager(Security.java:99)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:70)
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:59 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
jvm 1    | 2022.08.02 16:08:59 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p.EsManagedProcess] Failed to check status
jvm 1    | org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.lang.InterruptedException
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2695)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:151)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:64)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:92)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:77)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:62)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:223)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:288)
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1048)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:243)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:75)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2692)
jvm 1    |  ... 10 common frames omitted
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I have checked lots of StackOverflow Questions and solutions regarding same But still can't figure it out.

I would really appreciate for your help.

Comment: try ```brew install openjdk@17``` this works for me

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same issues.
In my system initially Java 1.8.0_371 then i installed latest JAVA SDK 20 from [this official site.](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk20-mac)  still faced same issue because of different version of JAVA SDK so you need to install either JAVA 11 or JAVA 17 version as per SonarQube documentation.

To resolve above issue i followed bellow steps

> 1. Install JDK 17

```
 brew install openjdk@17Install
```

> 2. open your system terminal shell environment file // it may be different in your system (**.zshrc** or **.bash**) check onetime for your system and set accordingly.

```
open .zshrc
```

> 3. Add PATH in terminal configuration file

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH"
```

> 4. again try to re-run SonarQube

```
sh /Applications/SonarQube/bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh console
```